# Including Special Characters when Querying a Title as Variable in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

That title is a mouthful...let me break it down.

I am grabbing a list of posts from a category, matching the post title to the category name. Pretty rad...and it works, *mostly...*

Here's my code...

```
<?php
    global $more;
    $more = 0;

    $page_cat = $post->post_title; //copy the page title
    $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name='.$page_cat);

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts('category_name='.$page_cat.'&paged='.$paged);
?>


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class('gallery-item'); ?>>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <?php $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $featuredImage; ?>" class="fancybox" rel="group" title="<?php the_title()?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'medium'); } ?></a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

This works for most titles. A page with the title of TEST will bring back posts in the category of TEST, TEST STUFF brings back TEST STUFF, etc.

What **doesn't** work is if the title has any special characters. For example TEST & STUFF shows nothing, even though there is a category called TEST & STUFF. TEST(STUFF) also won't work.

So how can I include the special characters in the title, or strip them from both the variable and the title, without affecting the front end display of the title?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress query is based on your **SLUG** and not based on your category name

so for example a **TEST & STUFF** will become **test-stuff**

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely accurate in this case. Like I said, Test Stuff (which has a slug of test-stuff) is working correctly to pull the category Test Stuff.

In this case, I believe I'm querying the post title, not the slug.